# Is it possible to set Ion-Slides to only move in 1 direction?

Tags: ionic-framework

Once I get to the final slide I want to disable the bounce effect that happens when you try and swipe further. I have ion-option-buttons on the final page and swiping them causes the screen to wobble due to the slides.

I still want to be able to move back to the left / previous slide

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't using the [Swiper](http://idangero.us/swiper/#.Vmc1J-ODFBc) widget I would recommend it because it offers a lot more flexibility/options with your slide boxes.  (Ionic documention on it [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSlides/), as well).

All you need to do is watch the slide delegate, if you hit the last slide, lock sliding to next (stops the bouncy effect you mentioned). Then unlock sliding if you are not on the last slide.

```
$scope.$watch('data.sliderDelegate', function(newVal, oldVal) {
  if (newVal != null) {
    $scope.data.sliderDelegate.on('slideChangeEnd', function() {
      $scope.data.currentPage = $scope.data.sliderDelegate.activeIndex;
      if($scope.data.currentPage == $scope.data.lastSlide){
        $scope.data.sliderDelegate.lockSwipeToNext();
      }
      else{
        $scope.data.sliderDelegate.unlockSwipeToNext();
      }
      $scope.$apply();
    });
  }
});
```

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZBeaRR) for the exmaple.

Comment: cheers! Unfortunately I didn't end up using the code as the slide boxes and options buttons didn't go well together aesthetically. As is the way of things. Hopefully this helps out someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I just managed this in Ionic 4.0, and though that someone might find some value in it.

You can use the command:

```
this.slides.lockSwipeToNext(true);
```

To prevent the user from swiping right. There is similarly another command to prevent it going left:

```
this.slides.lockSwipeToPrev(true);
```

I placed it in the " ionViewWillEnter()" function to initially disable the swiping, then created a function that I call whenever I want to manually move to the next slide like this:

```
ionViewWillEnter(){
    this.slides.lockSwipeToNext(true);
  }

  nextSlide(){
    this.slides.lockSwipeToNext(false);
    this.slides.slideNext();
    this.slides.lockSwipeToNext(true);
  }
```

Hope this helps someone looking for a similar soution.